# How to set content-type for cross origin requests while sending credentials?

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

In your debugging tools, this request will be sent with `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` despite a different `Content-Type` requested. At least, credentials are sent.

```js
variable=window.atob('/P//SCnp6VL///9BidpJicBMietMi3QkUEiLrCSwAAAATIu8JMgAAABMi2wkWOnL9///SItFEEiLfCQ4SIkHSItFGEiJRwjpJfv///YFbLUhAAgPhTH8//9IjQ2uegEASI01dksBAEiNPRBpAQC6IAEAAOh29AAAZg8fRAAARItUJEhMi0QkWEiLXCRQSIusJLAAAADpc/f//0SLVCRISItcJFBIi6wksAAAAEWF0g+UwOmN9f//SIt8JCj/FQTNIQBIjTVTRwEAvwIAAAAxwOjJYQAAv38AAADoHwwBAA8fRAAAZi4PH4QAAAAAAEFXQVZJifZBVUFUSYnUVVNNicVIgeyYAAAAD7Y=');

document.getElementById("fetchIt").addEventListener("click", function(){
        fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/q/48691699/2284570",{
        credentials: 'include',
        mode:'no-cors',
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-receive-pack-result'}), method: 'POST', body: variable}) // Request something that may or may not redirect
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
            );
    });
```

```html
<input type="button" id="fetchIt" value="Press the button to launch the request">
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: but where is fetchit element in html

Comment: @Dipakchavda : fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You've set `mode:'no-cors'` but Content-Types that aren't valid values for a form element's [`enctype` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) require permission from the response to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

You will also need permission via CORS to read the response.

Don't set `mode:'no-cors'`.

Comment: But how can I send the request cross origin to a web server I don’t own ? What I’m currently seeing is the request is sent but with the wrong headers. Where is the current behavior describe in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-fetch ?

Comment: "But how can I send the request cross origin to a web server I don’t own ?" — If they don't give you permission to do it from the user's browser, you can't. That's rather the point. Make the request from your server instead.

Comment: "What I’m currently seeing is the request is sent but with the wrong headers." — Yes. You set the no-cors mode, so it makes the request and ignores any anything you do which would require permission via CORS. Change the content-type? Ignored. Read the response? Ignored.

Comment: Where is the behaviour you’re describing in [the spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-fetch) ? In other cases, this would trigger an error where nothing would be sent.

Comment: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode — *"no-cors": Restricts requests to using CORS-safelisted methods and CORS-safelisted request-headers. Upon success, fetch will return an opaque filtered response.*

Comment: "In other cases, this would trigger an error where nothing would be sent" — That's the point of no-cors mode. It reduces errors and warnings to simply being ignored.

Comment: It’s more than that : you can’t send post data with credentials cross origin with a regular `xmlhttprequest`.

Comment: @user2284570 — Well yes. Adding credentials (via HTTP headers) to a request is *another* thing you can't do without permission from CORS. It doesn't matter if you are using XHR or fetch. You still need to set the mode so it isn't no-cors, and to have CORS permission from the server.

Comment: Looks like I’ll need to use Flash player and 307 redirects.